# macOS Folders/Finder: What makes media columns (eg Album) become available?

Tags: macos, mp3, finder

In macOS (Catalina), regarding Finder & Folders.
Some folders seem to "know" they contain media files, others don't.

I don't use the iTunes/Music app.

In Finder, List-view, when I click on their headings, I can add extra columns such as Album and Genre.

However just now I created a new folder and placed some mp3 files inside it, but there are no "media" columns (eg Album, Genre).  These mp3 files do contain ID3v2 metadata of that type.

What is it that distinguishes / determines these two types of behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

The pragmatic explanation/solution seems to be that the folder name has to start with "Music’.
Doesn’t matter where it’s located. In my case my music is on an HFS+ formatted external disk.

So e.g. it works for “Music”, “Music Test”, “Musicbhuexnihuewc” or whatever.
But it’s case-sensitive, so e.g. doesn’t work for “music” or “MUsic”

Comment: Wow! Great find. I never knew this. But even if you go into `~/Movies` left-click your can see options like Dimensions, Duration, Title and Codecs.